# jQuery functions works only for every second

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this layout :

```
   <div class="sidebar">
   <div class="tabs">
      <div class="comments">
         <a href="#" class="c_button">Comments</a>
      </div>
      <div class="todo">
         <a href="#" class="t_button">To Do list / notes</a>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
         <div class="comments_cnt">
            Comments
            <form>
               <input type="text" value="write" id="post">
            </form>
            <br />
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="post()">Post it</a> <br />
         </div>
         <div class="todo_cnt">
            To do
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is jquery :

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".c_button").click(function() {
            {
                $(".todo_cnt").css("opacity", "0");
            } {
                $(".comments_cnt").css("opacity", "1");
            } {
                $(".comments").css("border-bottom", "0px")
            } {
                $(".todo").css("border-bottom", "1px solid black")
            }
        })
        $(".t_button").click(function() {
            {
                $(".todo_cnt").css("opacity", "1");
            } {
                $(".comments_cnt").css("opacity", "0");
            } {
                $(".comments").css("border-bottom", "1px solid black");
            } {
                $(".todo").css("border-bottom", "0px")
            }
        })
    })
</script>
<script>
    function post() {
        var post = $("#post").val(); {
            $('.comments_cnt').append('<div class="post_unrslvd">' + post + '<p><a href="#" class="resolve_button">Mark as resolved.</a></p></div>');
        } {
            $("#post").val('');
        }
        $('.resolve_button').click(function() {
            $(this).parents(".post_unrslvd").toggleClass('post_rslvd');
        });
    };
</script>
```

and I want to be able to add posts which could be marked as resolved later. The problem is that the `toggleClass` function works only for the every second post and I can't understand why ?

Comment: Really?? what is the use of extra '{' ? You wraped each line of code with brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are adding duplicate event handlers to the element...

```
function post() {
    var post = $("#post").val();
    $('.comments_cnt').append('<div class="post_unrslvd">' + post + '<p><a href="#" class="resolve_button">Mark as resolved.</a></p></div>');
    $("#post").val('');
};

//dom ready handler
jQuery(function ($) {
    //delegated event handler
    $('.comments_cnt').on('click', '.resolve_button', function () {
        $(this).closest(".post_unrslvd").toggleClass('post_rslvd');
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dyfj41p2/1/)

that is in the first call there is 1 click handler for the `resolve_button` so the toggle works fine... but when the `post` is called for the second time, the `resolve_button` button which was added in the first call will get another click handler(now it has 2 handlers)... so the toggle is called twice thus negating the effect.

Demo: [Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dyfj41p2/4/) - look at the console to see how many times it is getting called

Answer (score 0):

Your script is waiting for the post function to be called, then it is waiting for the resolve button to be clicked.

```
$("document").ready(function(){$('.resolve_button').click(function() {
    $(this).parents(".post_unrslvd").toggleClass('post_rslvd');
});
});
```

Should do the trick